# C# 7 Pattern Match with a tuple

Tags: c#, switch-statement, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

Is it possible to use tuples with pattern matching in switch statements using c# 7 like so:

```
switch (parameter)
{
   case ((object, object)) tObj when tObj.Item1 == "ABC":
        break;
}
```

I get an error that says `tObj does not exist in the current context`.

I have tried this as well:

```
switch (parameter)
{
   case (object, object) tObj when tObj.Item1 == "ABC":
        break;
}
```

This works fine:

```
switch (parameter)
{
   case MachineModel model when model.Id == "123":
        break;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use c# tuple value types in a switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355630/how-to-use-c-sharp-tuple-value-types-in-a-switch-statement)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remember that C#7 tuples are just syntactic sugar, so `(object, object)` is really just `System.ValueTuple<object, object>`.

I guess that the dev team didn't take this particular situation into account for the new syntax for tuples, but you can do this:

```
switch (parameter)
{
    case System.ValueTuple<object, object> tObj when tObj.Item1 == "x":
        break;
}
```

Also, since the "var pattern" will match anything and respect the type, the above can be simplified to:

```
switch (parameter)
{
    case var tObj when tObj.Item1 == "x":
        break;
}
```

Comment: @DavidArno Thanks for the edit, but there is one issue with using `var`. If `parameter` is of type `object` and the switch statement is also being used to check for type, it will fail. [For example](https://gist.github.com/WiredUK/21d1a61c01580a2fe7b055ec83b46889)

Comment: Good point. I had assumed from the question that `parameter` was a tuple, but that could be a bad assumption to make.

Comment: @DavidArno I think it almost certainly is, which is why I haven't tweaked your edit. Just thought it was worth mentioning here.