# Using `is` operator with value type tuples gives error

Tags: c#, valuetuple

I am trying to check if an `object` variable is `(int, int)` and if so I will use the casted variable so I have tried the codes below:

```cs
//this one gives the error
public void MyMethodWithIs(object val)
{
    if(val is (int id, int name) pair)
    {
        ConsoleWriteLine($"{pair.id}, {pair.name}");
    }
}

//This one works
public void MyMethodWithAs(object val)
{
    var pair = val as (int id, int name)?;
    if(pair!=null)
    {
        ConsoleWriteLine($"{pair.id}, {pair.name}");
    }
}
```

The `MyMethodWithIs` method gives the error below in the editor:

> No suitable deconstruct instance or extension method was found for type

**My Question**

Why one works fine but the other gives an error at all? I think `MyMethodWithIs` more readable and suitable to use for my case but I can't use it due to giving an error.

Comment: AFAIK value tuples don't store item name information, so there is probably no way to check if the items are id and name. I am guessing it might work without names `if (val is (int, int) pair)`

Comment: @Slai I also tried it, but the same error appears.

Comment: `if (val is ValueTuple<int,string> pair)` works though. Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706498/c-sharp-7-pattern-match-with-a-tuple

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using C# 8's pattern matching capabilities, you can write this:

```
if (val is (int id, int name))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"id: {id}; name: {name}");
}
```

However this boxes `id` and `name`, which is surprising. There's a [proposal to optimize this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/35686).

Below C# 8, you can write this:

```
if (val is ValueTuple<int, int> pair)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"id: {pair.Item1}; name: {pair.Item2}");
}
```

You can of course make it a bit clearer:

```
if (val is ValueTuple<int, int> pair)
{
    var (id, name) = pair;
    Console.WriteLine($"id: {id}; name: {name}");
}
```

It looks like you can also deconstruct the ValueTuple inline:

```
if (val is ValueTuple<int, int>(var id, var name))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"id: {id}; name: {name}");
}
```

... which is somewhat horrific, but [appears to be legal](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABADAAmwEYBuAWAChsBmQgJnwGF8BvS/Dw27AFnwFkAFAHlgAKzgBjGPgD2ASlbtOKgJYAzfINn5VUfADUIAGwCucACqmADsbgAeVQDsYSXS4B8WgG4QEulDdffycIMDh5eWUVDjYKGITCIgBOQVUUfHR8UPD5cnjEgF9o/GKKQqA==).

I might have expected `val is (int, int) pair)` to work, but it seems nobody's designed this case (yet).

Comment: The first code block gives the same error. The second one works but I don't want to use `Item1`, `Item2` etc.

Comment: @ilkerkaran It works in sharplab - might be new in C# 8. https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABADAAmwEYBuAWAChsBmQgJnwGF8BvS/Dw27AFnwFkAFAHlgAKzgBjGPgD2ASlbtOKgJYAzfINn5VULaoB2MgB5Jdx/AE9585So5sKDzgF97+dxVdA=

Comment: @ilkerkaran found another way, added to my answer

Comment: I think my editor  does not let me to use c#8 yet (I think because it is preview). Your updated answer is probably the closest I can get for now.