# Use pattern matching with a C# 7 tuple

Tags: c#, resharper

I have the following code:

```
object foo = ("hello", "world");
var bar = foo as (string, string)?;
if (bar != null) { Console.WriteLine(bar.Value.Item1); }
```

Edit: I should say that `foo` is just an example of a variable I might receive in `object` form but should be able to convert.

Resharper highlights the 'as (string, string)' and suggests I `Use Pattern Matching` and when I accept, this is the result:

```
object foo = ("hello", "world");
if (foo is (string, string) bar) { Console.WriteLine(bar.Item1); }
```

This looks like it should be ok but it does not compile as `(string, string)` is highlighted with the error `No 'Deconstruct' method with 2 out parameters found for type 'object'`

While this code transformation seems like a resharper bug, this is not strictly a resharper-specific question as I'd like to know how *should* I write this? My original code worked fine but is there a way I can do what my original code is doing with pattern matching?

Comment: Because `object` does not have a `Deconstruct()` method. Any particular reason why you use `object foo =` instead of `var foo = `?

Comment: In my program I'd be receiving an `object` that I'd be attempting to cast to `(string, string)` and I just did I `object foo = ("hello", "world")` as an example of such an object I might be passed

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Using `is` operator with value type tuples gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56103160).  [How to use C# pattern matching with tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63582128) also seems related.  Do either of those answer your question?  Also, are you using **C# 7** or **.NET 7**? .NET 7 [corresponds to C# 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version).

Comment: Both syntaxes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56103294/3744182) by canton7 to [Using `is` operator with value type tuples gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56103160/3744182) work with your `foo` object, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/zYIpMf.  Looks like a duplicate.

Comment: The first one did help as I think I'll just have to use `ValueTuple<string, string>` instead of `(string, string)`.

Comment: Filed a bug for R# - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-493832/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately resharper made your code erroneous.

```
var bar = foo as (string, string)?; // foo casts to tuple
...
if (foo is (string, string) bar) // there is no cast, foo is still object
```

```
var foo = ("hello", "world"); // can be a solution here, object causes the error after refactoring
```

Comment: Sorry I updated my original post to say that `foo` is just an example of a variable I might receive in object form but should be able to convert.