is it possible to add two values to a conditional statement switch C#
the fact is that I need to check two variables with a large number of values
, I would like to write something like for a more convenient and clean code:
                switch (a, b)
                {
                    case 0, 0:
                        break;
                    case 0, 1:
                        break;
                    case 0, 2:
                        break;
                    case 0, 3:
                        break;
                    case 1, 0:
                        break;
                    case 1, 1:
                        break;
                    case 1, 2:
                        break;
                    case 1, 3:
                        break;
                }

But that's the only way it works at the moment:
switch (a)
{
    case 0:
        switch (b)
        {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        switch (b)
        {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
        }
        break;
}

I expected that it would be possible to set the values as in the coordinate system

put the values in case block in parenthesis so case (0,0):

https://stackoverflow.com/q/44355630/17234028 maybe this solves your question

This question is similar to: How to use c# tuple value types in a switch statement. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You were thinking in the right direction, and all you had to do was add parentheses to the cases, then the compiler would understand that it was dealing with tuples:
switch (a, b)
{
    case (0, 0):
        break;
    case (0, 1):
        break;
    case (0, 2):
        break;
    case (0, 3):
        break;
    case (1, 0):
        break;
    case (1, 1):
        break;
    case (1, 2):
        break;
    case (1, 3):
        break;
}

If you need to assign something, then you can apply such a construction (starting from C#8):
var str = (a, b) switch
{
    (0, 0) => "A",
    (0, 1) => "B",
    (0, 2) => "C",
    (0, 3) => "D",
    (1, 0) => "E",
    (1, 1) => "F",
    (1, 2) => "G",
    (1, 3) => "H",
    _ => "?"
};


Thanks a lot, I'm just new to programming and didn't even think about it.
